# Personalizar o WYSIWYG do Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Colegas.

Estou usando o  WYSIWYG do Bootstrap, porém gostaria de retirar alguns botões, deixar somente do **Normal** até o **Underline**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que tenho é:

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
       $(".textarea").wysihtml5();
     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

O **bootstrap-wysihtml5** é simples, leve... E um tanto *limitado*. Esta configuração dos botões não está prevista em código. Para fazer isto, você precisa rodar um comando em JQuery para deletar os botões, depois que eles já tiverem sido inseridos na página, após a chamada de `wysihtml5();`.

Felizmente os botões são facilmente identificáveis pelo atributo `title`.

```
$('a[title="CTRL+B"]').remove(); // Remove o botão Bold
$('a[title="CTRL+I"]').remove(); // Remove o botão Italic
```